# Custom array for each object of the same class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object

I'm making tower defense game in unity. writing in c#. And I have gameObject Enemy which is using waypoints array to move along the map. I spawn thease enemy objects several times and they all move using the same waypoints array which is declared in separate class. I thought If I declare new private waypoints1 array inside enemy class. enemyies start to use waypoints1 array. And they did. But now they all are using the same waypoints1 array, becase it belongs to enemy class and they all are from the same class. So how can I declare Unique array for each member of enemy class ?

```
public class ONE : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject[] waypoints;

...
}

public class TWO : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject[] waypoints;

...

void Start () {

        for (int i = 1; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
{
waypoints[i].transform.position = new Vector3(waypoints[i].transform.position.x + Random.Range(-3, 3), waypoints[i].transform.position.y + Random.Range(-3, 3), 0);
}
}
```

Class one spawns class two object several times and I want each class two object to have unique waypoints array.

I've tried this

```
public class ONE : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject[] waypoints;

...
}

public class TWO : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject[] waypoints;
private GameObject[] waypoints1;
...

void Start () {
waypoints1=waypoints;
        for (int i = 1; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
{
waypoints1[i].transform.position = new Vector3(waypoints[i].transform.position.x + Random.Range(-3, 3), waypoints[i].transform.position.y + Random.Range(-3, 3), 0);
}
}
```

But it does not help. Each instance of class Two has the same Waypoints1 Array. Which is just updating each time I make a new object spawn.

Comment: As long as it's a non static property/field each object will have its own array instance (though it depends on how you are assigning it). Can you post some code?

Comment: You are probably 'reusing' the same array instance that you pass in the constructor. Every time you want to create new waypoints, you'll need to create a new array. _(this is because arrays are reference types)_ You could create a copy of the array in the constructor. This is only wild guessing, because you didn't attached any code.

Comment: Waypoint array is declared like  public GameObject[] waypoints;

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have a certain amount of routes an enemy can go, why dont you just create an routes-profile-array with different routes and call a random member of it while creating your object?

you may add a methode to make sure not to many objects are getting the same randomnumber just because of the low amount of total routes. (remember last called routes-profil member or something like that).